# Relative include paths of different Fortran preprocessors

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, intel-fortran, nag-fortran

Consider the following directory tree:

```
test.F90
test/
├─ a.inc
└─ b.inc
```

With the following file contents:

- `test.F90`:

```
#include "test/a.inc"
end
```

- `a.inc`:

```
#if defined(__GFORTRAN__) | defined(__PGI) | defined(__NVCOMPILER)
#  include "b.inc"
#else
#  include "test/b.inc"
#endif

#include "b.inc"
#include "b.inc"
```

- `b.inc`:

```
print*,'!'
```

The GNU (gfortran 11.1.0) and Nvidia (nvfortran 22.9) compiler preprocessors search for the file to be included in the directory relative to the current file. E.g. `b.inc` should be included inside of `a.inc` with `#include "b.inc"`.

The Intel (ifort 2021.8.0, ifx 2023.0.0) and NAG (nagfor 7.1) compiler preprocessors search for the file to be included in the directory relative to the first file to invoke `#include`. E.g. `b.inc` should be included inside of `a.inc` with `#include "test/b.inc"` because `a.inc` is included in `test.F90`. However, it only applies for the first `#include` command. In all consequent `#include` commands, the directory is "changed" to `test` and `#include "b.inc"` can be used. While multiple `#include "test/b.inc"` commands also work in the Intel compiler, the code doesn't compile with the NAG compiler if the consequent paths are changed to `test/b.inc`.

Is this the intended behavior of the Intel and NAG compiler preprocessors? Is there a way to make the behavior of the `#include` command independent of the used compiler (and avoid the first 5 lines in `a.inc`)?

Comment: I'll comment that the Intel compiler has an option `-assume [no]source_include` that affects this behavior. I believe it is honored by the Intel fpp as well. I agree with @francescalus that #include is not part of the Fortran language.

Comment: @francescalus I meant only the `#include` command. I know that the behavior of `#include` is not part of the Fortran standard. But my question is, if there is a way to achieve the same results without writing cumbersome `#if` statements for each compiler (preferably without something like CMake). And if I understand it correctly, `include` cannot replace `#include`.

Comment: @SteveLionel yes, I know. But I find the default behavior of the Intel compiler strange. Like described above, only the first `#include` statement should have the "full" path.

Comment: My comment was about Fortran's include lines, not any particular preprocessor's `#include`. As you've clarified that part of the text, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @SteveLionel I tested it: `-assume [no]source_include` doesn't seem to affect anything in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel and NAG have replied and agreed that this behavior is a bug of their preprocessors (fpp and fdfpp, respectively). This bug will be fixed in future releases. (The bug report for the Intel compiler is CMPLRLLVM-45307.)

A somewhat not very elegant solution to make this preprocessor behavior compiler-independent is to change the directory tree: distribute the files in different folders **on the same level**, and, in the path of `#include`, always go up one level in the directory tree first and then to the desired file.

### Example

- Directory tree:

```
d1/
├─ test.F90
└─ b.inc
d2/
├─ a.inc
└─ b.inc
```

- `d1/test.F90`:

```
#include "../d2/a.inc"
end
```

- `d2/a.inc`:

```
! Even though "d2/b.inc" is in the same directory as "d2/a.inc", go up one level first
#include "../d2/b.inc"
#include "../d2/b.inc"

#include "../d1/b.inc"
```

- `d2/b.inc`:

```
print*,'Hello from d2/b.inc'
```

- `d1/b.inc`:

```
print*,'Hello from d1/b.inc'
```

All compilers will print the expected output:

```
 Hello from d2/b.inc
 Hello from d2/b.inc
 Hello from d1/b.inc
```

Comment: This issue was fixed in the version 2024.0 of the Intel compiler (ifx).